# Can I add a collection view to a collection view section header?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

So I'm trying to figure out how to add two collection views on the name view controller. Right now the current collection view I have is a vertical scrolling collection view that displays users posts on the feed. I would like to add a "people to follow" section that scrolls horizontally on the top.  Please note I would like the horizontal collection view to scroll down with the whole view.

Something that will look like this

[image]

I thought about adding a section header, then trying to add a collection view in that but I'm not sure if that is an illegal configuration.

I'm also not sure if I need to add 2 sections in the `number of sections` line.

Here is the collection view code currently.

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if posts.count > 4 {
            if indexPath.item == posts.count - 1 {
                fetchPosts()
            }
        }
    }

     func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if viewSinglePost {
            return 1
        } else {
            if posts.count == 0 {
            self.collectionView.setEmptyMessage("You haven't followed anyone yet.")
            } else {
                self.collectionView.restore()
            }
            return posts.count
        }
    }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PostsCell", for: indexPath) as! FollowingCell

        cell.delegate = self

        if viewSinglePost {
            if let post = self.post {
                cell.post = post

            }
        } else {
            cell.post = posts[indexPath.item]
        }

            handleUsernameLabelTapped(forCell: cell)
            handleMentionTapped(forCell: cell)
            handleHashtagTapped(forCell: cell)

        return cell
    }
```

Right now its just a basic feed that will fetch posts users upload. I thought it would be great user experience to include a people to follow section for new uses. What is the best way I should go about this?

Comment: Actually you want to add two collection views? Topper is horizontal and the bottom is vertical? If so, then I will answer your question elaborately

Comment: @AnkurLahiry Either Yes, however I want the horizontal collection view to scroll down with the entire view. Thats why my first thought was to add a section header and then place the horizontal collection view inside of that. Then return the profiles I want to showcase in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to add two collection views, one is for upper that is horizontal and the lower is vertical

- Add two collection views in the storyboard, give the first one a
  static height, take outlet from the storyboard and give outlet name something like `UpperCollectionView` and `LowerCollectionView`
- set delegate and data source to the collectionViews

```
upperCollectionView.delegate = self 
upperCollectionView.dataSource = self 
lowerCollectionView.delegate = self 
lowerCollectionView.dataSource = self
```

in case of all delegate methods , implement the collectionViews using `if - else` method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == upperCollectionView {
        //do code for upperCollectionView 
    } else {
        //do code for  lowerCollectionView 
    }
}
```

if look like complex, then I will suggest you to split, the upper part in the parent viewController and lower part in a container view.

If you want to scroll up the whole thing like a tableView scrolling, add all of this on a `UIScrollView` , this will handle the scrolling.

Comment: Will the upper one be fixed though? I still want it to scroll down with the whole view.

Comment: then you add a scroll view as a base and then set up the whole thing onto this

Answer (score 0):

if you ask me i would suggest a table view with 2 cells, fist cell is for collection view and second cell is your normal cell. in that way you can scroll in both directions. But if you want to use collectionview only then you need to add tag for collection view and configure it according to your tag i.e

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
if collectionView.tag == 1 {
// your horizantal collection view
} else {
//vertical one
}
```

Comment: So the only way to get it to scroll in both directions is adding a table view with 2 cells? Then add the collection views in each table view cell?

Comment: i am saying it's another way. not the only way. i've been using this from long time and it works perfect

Answer (score -1):

You could define the first index as another collection view.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more if you don’t mind?